# How to render random image on every refresh page

Tags: entities, media

I have got a content type and an `image` field.

How can I render the field with a random image at every page refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously I write a small module for this purpose, named [Many to one image](https://bitbucket.org/mohamadaliakbari/many_to_one_image)

This is a small display formatter, Download and install then go to manage display and select it.

Comment: thank you but i use cycle plugin on format. How can i use cycle and your module same time?

Comment: I was searching to find a way to chain display formatters, but unfortunately there isn't any way in drupal to do that. You should write your own display formatter. its a simple module. look at `Many to one image` source code ;)